# android fragment addToBackStack(null) :how to add the same fragment to stack just one time?

Tags: android, fragment

when fragment use addToBackStack(null) method and click a method many times in an activity, the fragment page will save to back stack everytime, when I press back key, it will restore the same page, how to add the same fragment to stack just one time?

```
    mSettingBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SettingFragment settingFragment = new SettingFragment();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            transaction.replace(R.id.left_framelayout, settingFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When adding your `Fragment` to the backstack you should also pass a `TAG` to be able to identify that `Fragment`:

```
 .addToBackStack(SettingsFragment.TAG);
```

Prior to adding the `Fragment` you will be able to check if this `Fragment` is allready in the backstack using :

```
 getFragmentMangager().findFragmentByTag(SettingsFragment.TAG);
```

This will return `null` if the `Fragment` is not allready added.

Comment: Param passed to `addToBackStack()` can be used to retrieve the whole `BackStackEntry` object, not just a single fragment. In order to set the fragment tag, consider using 3-param versions of `add(int, Fragment, String)` and `replace(int, Fragment, String)`

Comment: so how would you retrieve the fragment by tag after hitting the back button?  Where and how would this be done?  Something like:  ListFragment 1 (click listView row, commit transaction with tag) >>> ListFragment 2 >>> (click) BACK BUTTON >>> retrieve/restore ListFragment 1 via tag without reloading data

Comment: @whyoz the `Fragment` will be restored for you, you don't have to manually re-add it or whatever, this will be done by Android, if you properly used `Fragments` and the back stack

Comment: what if the Fragment is reusing the same class?  Say Fragment 1 is named "LF" and you want to click on a row and load another "LF" (Fragment 2).  Fragment 1 passes a string to Fragment 2 which loads different data, but it's using the same class (LF).  Logic would say use that string like addToBackStack(string), then I hit back and getFragmentMangager().findFragmentByTag(string) returns null??  I am using replace instead of add if that makes a difference.