# Sending Tag or string to back method

Tags: android, callback

I want to  send a tag or string to `onBackPressed()` method via `addToBackStack()` method. I don't know how I can send a tag (or string) and how I can give this tag.

I read this, but I can't understand how can I use this. What is `SettingsFragment.TAG`?

When I get this tag or string, I want to be able to check this value with an `if` statement.

Please simple explain this to me.

[android fragment addToBackStack(null) :how to add the same fragment to stack just one time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518086/android-fragment-addtobackstacknull-how-to-add-the-same-fragment-to-stack-jus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SettingsFragment.TAG is a class constant for the SettingsFragment class(as the all caps indicates), probably defined in SettingsFragment as follows :

```
public static final String TAG = "com.example.app_name.SettingsFragment.tag";
```

If you define a different tag for each Fragment, you can identify them later using

```
Fragment findFragmentByTag (String tag)
```

**EDIT :**
To pop a Fragment from the backstack, you can use the following :

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.popBackStack ("SettingsFragment.TAG", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: Why you give me negative ? I didnt know about TAG.. anyway, i declare TAG variable and i set this in addToBackStack in my fragment but i don't know how can i know in onBackResume() , do i pop second fragment (with TAG variable in addToBackStack). please more explain because i want accept your answer but i cant understand good :)

Comment: I didn't vote your question down, someone else did ... I don't quite understand what you're trying to do here, but to pop (remove) a fragment from backstack, see my EDIT.

Comment: I could solve my problem and i have a new question but this sit not allow to me ask question :( I accept any answer but again not allow