# What is the purpose of null in addToBackStack(null)?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new to Andoid development and I have created a snippet for replacing fragments programetically.

I followed the [guide on android developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

I have create a method named `selectFrag` and fired it on button click:

```
public void selectFrag(View view)
{    
    Fragment fr;    
 
    if(view == findViewById(R.id.showsecond)) {
        fr = new secondfragment();
    } else {
        fr = new firstfragment();
    }
         
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_place,fr);
            
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                
    ft.commit();    
}
```

Code works perfectly and I understand everything except `addToBackStack(null)`.

I experimented and understood that this method is for adding the fragment to the back button's stack, so that if we click back button, it do not leave the screen and show the previous work.

But, I do not understand what `null` shows here. I searched on web but I only knew that it is a `TAG` and we could use [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14518462/3830694).

So, my question is very simple :**What is meant by `null` here? or What does `null` do?**

(sorry for my bad English.)

Comment: @nem I know what is null in java but I want to know why null in addToBackStack()? what is the purpose of null in ""this"" method?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)), it is pretty clear:

```
public abstract FragmentTransaction addToBackStack (String name)
```

> Add this transaction to the back stack. This means that the transaction will be remembered after it is committed, and will reverse its operation when later popped off the stack.

Parameters

```
name // An optional name for this back stack state, or null.
```

So your parameter is **optional** and represents the name of the fragment.

If you just want to add this transaction to the back stack and don't need to access it later then you can put `null` as the name.

In this context, `null` in plain English means "I don't need a name for this fragment". That is why it says the name is optional. If you do put a name you can use that name later. If you put a `null` that just means "add this fragment to the back stack and I don't need it anymore".

The use of the name is to identify that specific fragment. This can be useful for example if you want to obtain that fragment from the `FragmentManager`:

```
addToBackStack (FRAGMENT_NAME);
getFragmentMangager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_NAME);
```

Comment: Could you think of any real world scenario where having a fragment name instead of null could come in handy. I have so far never used anything other than null and was curious where this could be useful.

Comment: @user3760100 to check if fragment is already displaying with old data and to recreate it with new data?

Comment: I tried test your example and I discovered that name serves to manage the back stack when pop the transaction by [`public abstract void popBackStack (String name, int flags)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager#popBackStack(java.lang.String,%2520int))

Answer (score 8):

**Just want to clarify, the 'name' used in addToBackStack(name) can't be used for retrieving the fragment by calling fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag). The 'tag' is different from the 'name'.**

The 'tag' used in add/replace(id, fragment, tag) is used to retrieve the fragment by calling fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag).

However, the 'name' used in addToBackStatck(name) is used to control to which fragment you want to pop the fragment back stack by calling popBackStatck/Immediate(name, flags). So if I have a fragment stack with named fragments: A, B, C and D with A at the bottom. When you call popBackStack(B, XXX_EXCLUSIVE), then your fragment back stack will be like: A and B after the call. Without the name, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not use  .addToBackStack(null);
if you are trying to popthe Backstack chances are that it might throw 
java.lang.IllegalStateException  as it wont be having valid reference to  Popout the last item which is added. This needs to be checked... i am not 100%  sure.