# What to use in ViewPager Navigation - A fragment-to-fragment or fragment-to-activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

What is better to implement in ViewPager?

1. A fragment that opens another fragment by replacing fragment.

OR

2. A Fragment which opens an activity by intent.

I have used both and both have their own drawbacks.

Problems with 1st.

1. It shows viewPager tabs and not that parent "back arrow" when in
   2nd fragment.
2. It causes ANR errors with strange logcat errors when going to back
   stack. (Not everytime, and this is causing me pain in my head). (see logcat below)

Problems with 2nd.

1. It goes from fragment to activity, but after returning from 2nd to
   first, upon pressing on back button, it again goes back to activity
   and after one more press of back button it goes to very first state
   of fragment/viewpager/mainActivity.

**Logcat**

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.widefide.musicplayer, PID: 14058
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.widefide.musicplayer/com.widefide.musicplayer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3947)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at com.widefide.musicplayer.Fragments.Playlists.PlaylistsFragment.onActivityCreated(PlaylistsFragment.java:72)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1797)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:979)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1120)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1929)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
            at com.widefide.musicplayer.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:127)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3947)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: You decide. Both issues look solvable (apart from the viewpager still showing tabs), you should just show some code.

Comment: I mean which is better to use? If you had to implement one, which one would you?

Comment: There's no preferable choice, it's up to the content. Showing a list of contacts and by clicking on a contact you go to his profile page? Better go into a new activity. Showing a list of simple strings which the user can edit by clicking? Better to stay there. It depends on design choices, on how you arranged your tabs, ...

Answer (score 2):

In **1st**, you can replace `fragment` itself by notifying parent `Activity` and `Activity` will replace that `fragment` with some other `fragment`. You still have control of `Toolbar` from your `Activity`. You can do this by either [default fashion](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) (with `interface`) or by using [Bus events (`Otto`)](http://square.github.io/otto/)

In **2nd**, which i would prefer this, you easily open `activity` with intent and you can control your back press by either `onBackPressed` or [fragment backstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518086/android-fragment-addtobackstacknull-how-to-add-the-same-fragment-to-stack-jus).

Answer (score 0):

From 1st problem in first case it is clear that you want a new screen so best will be a new activity. Problem in second solution seems like a bug, post the code so we can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager is a Fragment to Fragment Navigation.

You have to pass list of fragment. When you scroll the page the fragment will be replaced with next fragment.

[Refer this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)